# cannot convert from 'System.Reflection.Assembly - MEF scoping

Tags: c#, mef

I am trying to get get MEF scoping working in a test library .Net 4.7.1 and am getting three errors with the below command

```
var configuration = new ContainerConfiguration()
                .WithAssembly(typeof(MefScope).Assembly, conventions);
```

where MefScope is the class in which the above line is occurring (line 32)

The errors I'm getting are

```
Error   7   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Reflection.Assembly 
[c:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.1\mscorlib.dll]' to 
'System.Reflection.Assembly'    D:\MyTest\___rc\PB\MyTest.Test\MefScope.cs  33  35  MyTest.Test

Error   6   The best overloaded method match for 'System.Composition.Hosting.ContainerConfiguration.WithAssembly(System.Reflection.Assembly, System.Composition.Convention.AttributedModelProvider)' 
has some invalid arguments  D:\MyTest\___rc\PB\MyTest.Test\MefScope.cs  33  21  MyTest.Test
```

and

```
 Error  5   The type 'System.Reflection.Assembly' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced.
 You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Reflection, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.   D:\MyTest\___rc\PB\MyTest.Test\MefScope.cs  32  13  MyTest.Test
```

I'm assuming this is some kind of dll mismatch but I can't figure out where System.Reflection, Version=4.0.0.0 is. Perhaps I'm missing the point all together.

Could some kind soul point me in the right direction. I need to be using .Net 4.5.1.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be something happening within a single project. When I created a new project and added the same code (and references) the issue went away.